# HTML5 video z-index is not working on iPad

Tags: css, html, html5-video

**Please fix my issue on the iPad .**

I have two div's. One is video div and the other a button div. When I am scrolling browser video is background of the button div. When I start touching button div, action is not responding and action over to video play or play and so on.

what do I have to do ....

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">                     
   <video id="vid" width="480" height="260px" controls style="position: absolute; left: -5px; right: 0; margin: 0 auto; top: 0; display: none;">
      <source src="../activity/video/tusnami.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
      <source src="../activity/video/tusnami.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
      <source src="../activity/video/tusnami.ogv" type="video/ogv"></source>
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>                     
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width: 480px; height: 260px; z-index:10;" onclick="Test()"></div>
```

Comment: The questions is incomplete and unclear.

Comment: Your code contains lots of errors. The `height` attribute on the `video` tag should not have `px` in it. Also, in the `style` attribute of the second `<div>`, you have `width=480px` instead of `width:480px` (equal sign instead of colon), and the same for `height`.

Answer (score 2):

iOS (Safari or iBooks) is extremely finicky about videos as regards page layout (and other issues as well, such as when they are loaded). The most common issue is that the video just fails to appear, often leaving a blank area.

The only completely reliable approach is to have a single video element, in the normal page flow, normal positioning, no overlays, no turning on or off via the `display` property, no playing with the `z-index` property as you are trying to do.

Whatever else works or does not work, the video will not play if it is not in the foreground. iOS apparently has some logic to determine if that is the case. It won't even start to load the video. Calls to `video.play()` will fail with a DOM error (to check this, add `try {video.play();}catch(e){alert(e);}` to your code in the appropriate place). So at a minimum, before you try to play the video, you will have to change z-indexes around so that the video is "on top", and also change the `display: none` property.

If you want to display something in place of the video before it plays, there is always the `poster` attribute, which works well. But there is no way to return to it after the video plays AFAIK. You could try replacing the `poster` attribute, possibly followed by a `video.load()`, and see how far that gets you, but to my knowledge the HTML5 spec does not require that the poster **ever** be displayed again once the video has played its first frame.

On iPhone the issues are even worse, since videos play only full-screen, and as far as I can tell, even the dimensions of the `video` element are ignored in favor of a default rectangular size.

You should also be aware that there are reports that event handling on videos is funny. I've heard stories about touch events not being propagated properly.

With regard to your particular question, what does `Test()` do? Also, the final `div` seems to be empty, was there supposed to be a "Press Me!" or something in there?